# Proper syntax for an AMPScript block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Hope you can help me on this.
Still a newbie, but I'm finding myself using AMPScript more and more when creating dynamic content for my marketing sends.

But I constantly find an inconsistency in how examples of AMPScript are posted.

Sometimes I find AMPScript encapsuled like this:

```
<script runat="server" language="ampscript">
VAR @dyncountry, @country

SET @dyncountry = UPPERCASE([Country Code]) 

IF 
@dyncountry == "DK" THEN 
SET @country = "5315" 
ELSE
SET @country = "5365"
ENDIF

Output(ContentBlockByID(@country))

</script>
```

And sometimes like this:

```
%%[
VAR @dyncountry, @country

SET @dyncountry = UPPERCASE([Country Code]) 

IF 
@dyncountry == "DK" THEN 
SET @country = "5315" 
ELSE
SET @country = "5365"
ENDIF

Output(ContentBlockByID(@country))

]%%
```

I've tried both and they seem to output exactly the same.
So, is one the better option.. Or do they come with different advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have the same general effect while rendering. See below reference material from SFMC for more information on the technical aspect.

I tend to use the script tag for my ampscript, but mostly only due to aesthetics.  In using the %%[ and ]%%, the ampscript can show up, not just in third party editors, like Dreamweaver, and browsers but also inside the editor preview inside SFMC.  When you place it into the script tag, by default all editors hide the content inside (as long as you format it correctly).

A lot of the people I work with do not understand technology that well, so the less I need to explain why there is, as they call it, 'gobblety gook' on the email, the better.

**Below taken from [AMPScript Syntax Guide](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/) - more specifically from [function calls](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_function_calls/) section:**

**Tag-based Syntax for AMPscript**
Tag-based syntax for AMPscript standardizes the syntax used to declare AMPscript blocks with the syntax of server-side JavaScript. This syntax eases the burden on developers to write in a different syntax when switching between AMPscript and server-side JavaScript. Use the information below to format your AMPscript calls. AMPscript calls are case-insensitive.

**Minimum Syntax**
This sample illustrates the minimum syntax necessary to declare an AMPscript block.

```
<script runat=server language=ampscript>
    [INSERT AMPSCRIPT HERE]
</script>
```

**Full Syntax**
This sample illustrates the complete syntax used to declare an AMPscript block.

```
<script runat=server language="ampscript" executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=test>
    [INSERT AMPSCRIPT HERE]
</script>
```

The AMPscript block must be closed in the same syntax that opens it. For example, if you open a block using `<script>`, you must close it with `</script>` and not ]%%.

**Delimiter Comparison**
The table below demonstrates the similarities between standard AMPscript delimiters and server-side delimiters.

**Standard AMPscript Delimiter**           
  **Tag-based AMPscript Delimiter**  

`%%[`                                               
`<script runat=server language=ampscript>`

`%%[[type=post;name=blockname]` `<script runat=server language=ampscript` 
                                                       `executioncontexttype="Post" executioncontextname=blockname>`

`]%%`                                                `</script>`

`%%[]%%`                                          `<script runat=server language=ampscript />`

Comment: I use the `%%[` `]%%` syntax exclusively -- mostly because I want people to know where the scripting is in the email or landing page.  I have a pretty good syntax highlighting system in Sublime Text that handles the AMPScript tags fine.  If I need to hide it, I'll use this trick: [Prettying Up AMPScript in Emails](https://sprignaturemoves.com/prettying-up-ampscript-in-emails/)

Comment: Absolutely - I just referenced that I use the script tag because my reviewers tend to get lost and confused when viewing the scripting.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same.  The [**Server-Side JavaScript Syntax Guide**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/)
says that:

> For the Language parameter, you can specify either JavaScript or
>   AMPscript. If no parameter is specified, the system defaults to
>   JavaScript.

Comment: Just to get it right.
The first example is AMPScript because it's declared in the language parameter.
The second example is AMPScript simply because AMPScript always starts and ends with %%[ and ]%%

...right?

Comment: As far as I know, YES.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to function the same, however [OMM](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/system_guides/what_happens_when_you_click_send/) does not give detail on AMPscript errors (in Send Preview) if you have tag-based delimiters; it just throws a generic error:

```
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a TreatAsContent function call. See inner exception for details.
An error occurred when attempting to parse HtmlEmailBody content for HTML content.
MemberID: 7230771
JobID: 0
ListID: 52
Content Begins With:
```

You need to change the delimiters to the standard delimiters to see error detail.

Comment: I will be honest, I have never heard of this before. I have spoken directly to the product directors that actually maintain the development of SFMC and they said that there is no difference.  The only assumption I can make is that prior to it hitting SFMC, your browser manipulates the code in some unexpected way that changes the output.

Comment: To clarify - I do not deny that this is an issue, and that you are correct - it just may be that the issue is browser based - e.g. your browser reads the scripts inside of %%[ and ]%% as normal 'text', whereas inside the script tag it would be rendered differently.

Comment: You are correct, I've just re-tested this and I can't reproduce the double space issue that I experienced before, however the error reporting is different. I have updated my answer to reflect this.